# How to set alarms in android

Tags: android

I am a newbie to android.

I am developing a prayer application. The functionality is the user will set a time and at that particular time a prayer will be played for the entire month.

So i am doing in this manner:

```
for (int counterAlarm = 0; counterAlarm < spanDays; ++counterAlarm) {


            alarmPendingIntent = CreatePendingIntent(context,
                    String.valueOf(100 + counterAlarm));
            SetAlarmForDay(context, calendarMorningReminder,
                    alarmPendingIntent);
            calendarMorningReminder.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            sbRequestCodes.append(String.valueOf(100 + counterAlarm));
            sbRequestCodes.append(";");
        }
```

The above for loop add all the alarms for the days, suppose the user chosses the time as 6.00 AM in the morning on the 1st day of the month then 30 alarms are registerd.

```
private static PendingIntent CreatePendingIntent(Context context,
            String requestCode) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ApplicationBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(Constants.INTENT_ACTION_ALARM_RAISED);

        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                Integer.parseInt(requestCode), intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private static void SetAlarmForDay(Context context, Calendar calendar,
            PendingIntent pIntent) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
        } else {

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
        }
    }
```

So i have two questions :

1. Registering all 30 alarms is this approach good enough in android. Or there is some better approach to solve this ?
2. Our application is backward compatible from android gingerbread, so we have used the `setExact()` method for version greater then kitkat and `set()` method for all other lower versions. Is this approach god enough ?

Please help.

Comment: I don't immediately see a problem or error in your code. Do you have an issue, or are you simply asking whether your code follows recommended standards of practice?

Comment: I think It would look fine I do not see any false part.

Comment: @Knossos - No the alarm are getting fired, what i am concerned about is the approach of mine is good or not, or there is a better approach.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar - Update my answer, do you the approach is good, with 30 registered alarms ?

Comment: Your method is fine. However, you will want to do it more than for 30 days correct? You will probably want prayer reminders everyday? You should in this case register may be 7. Each time, check how many are currently registered. If less than 7 are registered then register more alarms until there are 7.

Comment: @Knossos - Ok. And hat about the set() and setExact() method ? Is that fine ?

Comment: Yes, that looks to be fine. I see no problems there.